# add_post_meta not working within AJAX function

Tags: ajax, post-meta

I'm passing some data through AJAX to a function in my functions.php, and am trying to save that as metadata to post '101' with a key name "test1". My PHP function is:

```
function fztest(){

    $datum = $_POST['datum'];
    $post_ID = $_POST['post_ID'];

    add_post_meta($post_ID, 'test1', $datum);

    // And since $datum and $post_ID are correctly returning the values I want, but the meta is not saving, 
    // I've tried troubleshooting by putting some manual operations in various places below:

    add_post_meta(101, 'test2', 'foobar');

    wp_die();

    add_post_meta(101, 'test3', 'foobar');

}
add_action('wp_ajax_foobar', 'fztest');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_foobar', 'fztest');

add_post_meta(101, 'test4', 'foobar');
```

But when I try to return get_post_meta(101, 'test1'), for example - only 'test4' above works - it just returns an empty string for test1, test2 and test3.

My JS is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: fz.ajax_url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        action: "foobar",
        datum: "foobar",
        post_ID: fz.post_ID,
    },
    success: function(response){

    }
})
```

... and that is correctly passing the values through to the PHP function, and logging a response when I have tried one.

I can't see why add_post_meta would not work in the PHP function? There's a similar question here where the solution indicates it clearly should and CAN work. [How do I update_post_meta() or add_post_meta() with an AJAX call](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/201648/how-do-i-update-post-meta-or-add-post-meta-with-an-ajax-call). And their code looks the same as mine as far as I can see.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: there are no strings/quotes around your `$_POST` is this intentional? My understanding is that's invalid PHP, and `$_POST[post_ID];` should be `$_POST['post_ID'];`. I also see it's reading `datum` in the AJAX handler, but `datum` is nowhere to be found in your AJAX code. The `add_post_meta` for `test3` will never run because there's a `wp_die` just before it. From what I can tell, your PHP error log should be full of warnings and errors from that code. It's also not returning a response so there's no way to get info directly from the AJAX call

Comment: Sorry - the datum/subject business was sloppy editing within StackExchange. Have corrected that in edits. Also added in quote marks, although it was processing that ok. 

I agree that I didn't expect 'test3' to work, but was getting desperate!

It's still not making any difference though - any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I see, just be mindful that you may have edited out the problem trying to hide your client/production code, have you been able to reproduce the problem using the modified version in your question? How did you confirm the AJAX endpoint is successfully receiving  the post ID and data? And you've directly confirmed that `fz.post_ID` has the expected value? Note that checking if the post meta is present afterwards is an integration test and you can't draw any conclusions beyond wether it worked or didn't work which isn't fine grained enough to answer it

Comment: note that in this case `update_post_meta` should suffice and would be more reliable, but there is nothing wrong with your usage of those functions, the problem is elsewhere, it's more likely the variables being passed into the function don't have the values you think they do. Right now there's no evidence the AJAX endpoint is being called correctly, `fz.ajax_url` may not have a valid value, there's no response to check, and no way to test for success or failure from JS

Comment: I started off building up a bog standard AJAX function step-by-step:  checking that fz.post_ID had the correct value; that it was being passed to functions.php, was getting returned to the JS file and was registering via a console.log(response). All worked perfectly. It was only when I tried saving the data that any error was encountered. Have also tried it with update_post_meta, and no cigar either... :/

Comment: and what's the return value of `update_post_meta`? Keep in mind it is possible to have more than one meta with the same key on a post, so `add_post_meta` might build up multiple post meta keys and values with the same name but different values. What specifically was getting returned to the JS file? I know you've made your code generic to hide things but you've removed a lot of the context and debugging statements that save time in the process, can you add them back in? Otherwise there's a long list of basic questions to ask that could be easily avoided